# How to change price for several products individually using a single script function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, css, django

Please take a look at my code [here](https://github.com/apul1421/table-client-side-app-retake/blob/master/src/products/templates/products/product_list.html). The page is deployed [here](http://table.pythonanywhere.com/products/).

I'm using an ID `price` to refer to the price of an item. A general jQuery function attempts to change the price of every item on a selection change (with respect to the size of the item), as below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".variation_select").change(function(){
          var price = $(".variation_select option:selected").attr("data-price");
          var sale_price = $(".variation_select option:selected").attr("data-sale-price");
          if (sale_price != "" && sale_price != "None" && sale_price != null ) {
            $("#price").html("<h4>" + "₹&nbsp;" + sale_price + " <small class='og-price'>" + "₹&nbsp;" + price + "</small></h4>");
          } else {
            $("#price").html("₹&nbsp;" + price);
          }
        });
    });
```

As the items and their data come from the backend and I have multiple items, the HTML understandably replicates and as a result, I have more than a single element with the same ID. The HTML that displays the item's price is as below:

```
<div class="row">
{% for object in object_list %}
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    {% if object.productimage_set.count > 0 %}

    {% for img in object.productimage_set.all %}
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img class='img-responsive' src="{{ img.image.url }}" >


    {% endfor %} 

    {% endif %}



      <div class="caption">
        <h3 style="text-align: center;">{{ object.title }}</h3>

        <form id='add-form' method='GET' action="{% url 'cart' %}">
        <p id='jquery-message' class='lead'></p>



    {% if object.variation_set.count > 1 %}
        <h4 id='price' style="text-align: center; display: block;">₹&nbsp;{{ object.variation_set.first.price }}</h4>

        <select name= 'item' class='form-control variation_select' style="margin: 0 auto; width: 30%; display: block;">
                {% for vari_obj in object.variation_set.all %}
                    <option data-sale-price="{{vari_obj.sale_price}}" data-price="{{ vari_obj.price }}" value="{{ vari_obj.id }}">{{ vari_obj }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
                </select>
        <br>


        {% else %}



        <input type="hidden" name='item' value='{{ object.variation_set.first.id }}' />
                    <h4 id="price" style="text-align: center; display: block;">₹&nbsp;{% if object.variation_set.first.sale_price %}

                    {{ object.variation_set.first.sale_price }}
                        &nbsp;<small style="text-align: center; display: inline-block" class="og-price">₹</small>
                    <small class="og-price">{{ object.variation_set.first.price }}</small>

                    {% else %}



                    {{ object.variation_set.first.price }}

                    {% endif %}

                </h4>




        {% endif %}

        <p style="text-align: center;">{{object.description}}</p>
        <br>
        <input class='form-control' type='number' name='qty' value='1'  style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; width: 30%; display: block;" /> 
        <br>
        <p><input id='submit-btn' type='submit'  value='Add to Cart' class="btn btn-primary"  style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto; padding: 5% 10%; display: block;" />


        </p>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

As I can understand, the price of only the first item changes, since its the first block of code with a unique ID instance, rest all that follow are violate the rule of having unique IDs. Hence their prices don't change. While putting them in the same class changes their prices together, something else I don't want too. How can I solve this problem of having multiple items in my page and still being able to select their prices individually?

Comment: I don't understand why the fact that they come from the backend "understandably" means they share the same ID. Why can't you give them different IDs? Note, you're not showing where you're looping, which would make this easier to answer.

Comment: 1) Because I'm using a general code (snippet no.2 above) to generate the markup of all the several objects/items in the `object_list`, I cannot give them different IDs. I simply created a singular version of the code that generates multiple instances of itself, depending on the number of items/objects it needs to fetch. If you take a look at the code, you'll understand.
2) Point noted, will update the snippet shortly.

Comment: But "cannot give them different IDs" simply does not follow from "using a general code". You have the object, you can generate an ID that is as unique as you like: for example `<h4 id='{{ object.id }}-price'>`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for diverting me along those lines.

Answer (score 0):

On your changed function, you can use the jquery "closest()", like this.

```
$(this).closest("#price").html("₹&nbsp;" + price);
```

It will fetch the nearest object with an ID of "price" and change its html content.

I hope it helps. You can read more on jquery [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) api docs.